# Copying models in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Suppose I have a tensorflow model `model = My_model()`.

I'm trying to understand what the following line of code does:

`model_b = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.output)`

Does it copy `model`'s architecture? It's weight values?

Thanks

Comment: This can be found in the Keras docs: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#use-the-same-graph-of-layers-to-define-multiple-models

Comment: yeah, thanks, I was trying to understand if they share weights as well as architecture

Comment: That is answered in the documentation, they share weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"model_b" will have the same architecture as "model", BUT this will NOT copy the weight values.  That means that the two models will share the SAME set of weights.  Use `tf.keras.models.clone_model` to make a distinct copy.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I understood. Are you saying that ```model``` and ```model_b``` would be different names of the same instance?

Comment: No, they would be distinct Model objects, but the Layers themselves would be common.